# LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions never resolved on Android

Tags: android, react-native, fbsdk

i got the sdk working for IOS, but for Android, as i call LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions, the promise never gets resolved.
Modal appears, I insert the facebook credentials, I authorize the app, modal closes but no promise resolve.

This is the button click code (working for IOS)

```
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email',    'user_friends', 'user_birthday']).then(
                        function(result) {
                             console.log('Login success')
                            } else {
                              console.log('Login error')
                            }
                        },
                        function(error) {
                            console.log('Login error')
                        }
                    );
```

MainApplication.java

```
package com.situa;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;

import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientPackage;
import com.react.rnspinkit.RNSpinkitPackage;
import com.cmcewen.blurview.BlurViewPackage;
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;
import com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.RNDeviceInfo;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {

    @Override
    public boolean isDebug() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
        return mCallbackManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        // If you want to use AppEventsLogger to log events.
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
                new LinearGradientPackage(),
                new RNSpinkitPackage(),
                new BlurViewPackage(),
                new ImagePickerPackage(),
                new RNDeviceInfo(),
                new MapsPackage()
        );
    }


}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.situa;

import com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.SplashActivity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends SplashActivity {

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        MainApplication.getCallbackManager().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

In AndroidManifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
...
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
...
<activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>`

settings.gradle

```
include ':react-native-fbsdk'
project(':react-native-fbsdk').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android')
```

build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-share')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-geocoder')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-blur')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-spinkit')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    debugCompile project(path: ':react-native-navigation', configuration: 'libraryDebug')
    releaseCompile project(path: ':react-native-navigation', configuration: 'libraryRelease')
}
```

RN 0.35

react-native-navigation@2.0.0-experimental.105

react-native-fbsdk : 0.3.0

ANDROID Emulator   SDK 23

Comment: I saw you managed to find a solution through [GitHub](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/410). Would you be willing to post it as an answer here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the gist of the solution on github for future reference:

In MainApplication.java add this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    setActivityCallbacks(new ActivityCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
            // Do stuff
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
            // Do stuff
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    });

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    // If you want to use AppEventsLogger to log events.
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
}
```